# Error with rake deploy of Rally skeleton app

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2

I hate to ask such a basic question, but I receive the below error when trying to deploy the Rally skeleton app.  I am following along with the video Building Rally Apps - An Intro to Rally's 2.0 javascript SDK, by David Thomas.

The app correctly builds and works if I manually paste it into custom html app.

Error:

> C:\Users\U5930838\Documents\Rally Projects\New folder>rake deploy
>      Building App...
>
> > Created deploy/App.html
> >        Deploying to Rally...
> >        rake aborted!
> >        uninitialized constant Rally::AppSdk::Deployr::OpenSSL
> >        C:/Users/U5930838/Documents/Rally Projects/New folder/rakefile:471:in `rally_pos
> >        t'
> >        C:/Users/U5930838/Documents/Rally Projects/New folder/rakefile:224:in`login'
> >        C:/Users/U5930838/Documents/Rally Projects/New folder/rakefile:182:in `deploy'
> >        C:/Users/U5930838/Documents/Rally Projects/New folder/rakefile:56:in`block (2 l
> >        evels) in '
> >        Tasks: TOP => deploy => deploy:app
> >        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>
> C:\Users\U5930838\Documents\Rally Projects\New folder>

deploy.json:

```
{
"server": "https://rally1.rallydev.com",
"username": "my username",
"password": "my password",
"projectOid": "my projectOid"
}
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OpenSSL is not installed on your box. Try openssl -help in the command prompt. When it is installed, a list of commands is shown. This is a screenshot from my Windows box:

[image]

Rally app deployment process with rake was probably much more thoroughly tested in Mac or Linux environment where openssl is normally installed when installing ruby via rvm with openssl flag. I successfully tested deployment of an app from a Windows 7 box following David Thomas' video, but I had openssl already installed.